# To what Italian term does *nonce word* correspond?

Tags: word-choice

In English a *nonce word* is one coined on the spur of the moment. It works in its context but may never be used again.

To what Italian term does *nonce word* correspond?

Or, maybe, in Italian the *nonce word* phenomenon doesn't exist and so there is no parallel term.

Comment: it may be worth noting that when talking about cryptography the term *nonce* is usually not translated in Italian.

Answer (score 9):

According to Treccani dictionary it would be "[occasionalismo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/occasionalismo/)", reported also on [Wikipedia](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occasionalismo_%28linguistica%29). I'm not sure how popular the notion is in Italian though. "[Hapax](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/hapax/)" is a related notion ([here](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hapax) on Wikipedia).

Note that Treccani Encyclopedia mentions "[occasionalismo](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/occasionalismo/)" only as a philosophical doctrine ([here](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occasionalismo) on Wikipedia).

Comment: the Treccani dictionary reports both uses http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/occasionalismo/

Comment: I thought that *hapax* (legomenon) was used for a word which is found only once in the corpus of a dead language. Does anyone use it for a current language?